# Why is my snap scrolling not working for this website I am trying to recreate?

Tags: html, css

I want to add snap scrolling to this webpage that I am trying to remake. When the user scroll I want the closest magazine to automatically vertically center to the page. Currently, nothing changes with the scrolling with the code I have now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Backstage Talks Magazine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
        <a href="#" class="mail">info@backstagetalks.com</a>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Backstage Talks is a magazine of casual, but in depth 
                dialogues on design and business. Our decisions shape 
                and influence this complex world—to have a chance to 
                make the right ones, we need to talk.</p>
            <p class="copyright">© 2023 <a href="#">Published by Büro Milk</a></p>
            <a href="#" class="privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
        </div>
        <div class="issues">
            <ul class="issues">
                <li><a href="#">Issue #7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Issue #6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Issue #5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Issue #4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Issue #3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Issue #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Issue #1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll-container">
        <div class="issue_six">
            <img src="backstagetalks_cover_issue_7.png" alt="Issue 6">
            <div class="centered">
                <p>Issue #7</p>
                <div class="buy">
                    <p><span class="buy-here">BUY HERE</span>  (Europe)</p>
                    <p><span class="buy-here">BUY HERE</span>  (UK & Overseas)</p>
                </div>
                <p>or in <span class="buy-here">selected stores</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="issue_five">
            <img src="backstagetalks_cover_issue_6.png" alt="Issue 5">
            <div class="centered">
                <p>Issue #6</p>
                <div class="buy">
                    <p><span class="buy-here">BUY HERE</span>  (Europe)</p>
                    <p><span class="buy-here">BUY HERE</span>  (UK & Overseas)</p>
                </div>
                <p>or in <span class="buy-here">selected stores</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #ff608c;
}

img, picture, svg, video {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 260px;
    height: auto;
}

.mail {
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
}

.description {
    position: fixed;
    width: 325px;
    bottom: 65px;
    left: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.copyright {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.copyright a {
    color: black;
}

.privacy {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
}

.issues {
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.issues a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.issue_six img, .issue_five img{
    width: 420px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.issue_five {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.buy {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.buy-here {
    color: white;
}

.scroll-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.issue_six, .issue_five {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

I was expecting each issue to vertically center smoothly as the user scrolled up or down.

Here is the website I am trying to recreate: [Backstage Talks](https://backstagetalks.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main change you need to make is to give your scroll container a specific height. Without this, the height of your scroll container will just grow to accommodate all the contents, so there is no overflow. You end up scrolling the body rather than the scroll container.

Note that you can snap to any descendant of your scroll container – the element does not have to be a direct child of the container. I have set the snap on the images rather than the spans.

After running this snippet, make sure to use the **full page** link and resize your browser window to see the proper effect.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 49%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 49%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 51%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 51%);
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 3px solid lime;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 75vh 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #bbbbbb7f;
  display: block;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>
    Text above the photo
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/250/150">
    Text below the photo
  </span>
  <span>
    Text above the photo
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/260/150">
    Text below the photo<br>Text below the photo<br>Text below the photo
  </span>
  <span>
    Text above the photo
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/270/150">
    Text below the photo<br>Text below the photo<br>Text below the photo<br>Text below the photo<br>Text below the photo
  </span>
  <span>
    Text above the photo<br>Text above the photo<br>Text above the photo<br>Text above the photo
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/252/150">
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/262/150">
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/272/150">
  </span>
</div>
```

After running this snippet, make sure to use the **full page** link and resize your browser window to see the proper effect.